# Convergence? $\sum_{n \in\mathbb{N} \frac{1}{n^2} =\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\frac{1}{8^2}...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Is it possible to determine the exact value of this convergent series?

$\sum_{n \in\mathbb{N}\text{ is not a multiple of 3}} \frac{1}{n^2} =\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{4^2}+\frac{1}{5^2}+\frac{1}{7^2}+\frac{1}{8^2}...$.

I know this will obviously be lesser than $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, but I wonder if the exact value of this series can be determined.

Comment: Why would it obviously be smaller than $\frac{\pi^2}6$? And by "a product of 3", do you mean a multiple of 3 (such as 3, 6, 9, 12, ...) or a power of 3 (such as 3, 9, 27, 81, ...)?

Comment: I don't understand what the sum is over.  What does "$n$ is not a product of $3$" mean?  Do you mean "$n$ is not a *power* of $3$"?  But that sum diverges.  Indeed, $\sum \frac 1{3k+1}$ diverges.

Comment: Surely $3$ divides $6$? I imagine the series above is divergent.

Comment: Ah, a minor edit of squaring...

Comment: Sorry guys, I made a mistake. I forgot to include the power of 2

Comment: But I still have no guess what "$n$ is not a product of $3$" means.  Which $n$ are you excluding?  A list might help.

Comment: Multiple of 3 or power of 3?

Comment: I mean, n is not a multiple of 3

Comment: Then why do you include $6$?

Comment: Sorry guys so many mistakes. I would mean 1/7^2 + 1/8^2... and so on

Comment: $\frac1{3^2}+\frac1{6^2}+\frac1{9^2}+\frac1{12^2}+\cdots=\frac{\pi^2}{54}$ so by subtraction you would get $\frac{4\pi}{27}$

Comment: Note that $\sum \frac 1{(3n)^2}=\frac 19\times \sum \frac 1{n^2}$.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge 1,\ 3\nmid n} \frac{1}{n^2} &=\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{(3n)^2} \\&=
\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{9} \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^2}  \\&=
\frac{8}{9} \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^2}\\ &= \frac{4\pi^2}{27}.
\end{align}

Comment: The question was edited to squares before you answered

Comment: @SineoftheTime: Yes, of course. Thank you.